# Get latest price on large table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using `10.4.11-MariaDB`.

My table **prices** has over `~8.931.870` records.

My table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `companies_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exchanges_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currencies_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrument_types_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `average` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `baseVolume` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quoteVolume` decimal(40,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_timestamp_gmtoffset` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_timestamp_timezone` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When executing the following query it takes quite some long time. Sometimes the query takes several minutes or I even get a `500` error code from my mysql db:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    prices p
WHERE
    p.id IN(
    SELECT
        MAX(pp.id)
    FROM
        prices pp
    GROUP BY
        pp.companies_id
) AND p.companies_id = 3431
ORDER BY
    p.created_at
DESC
```

The above query gives me the latest `price` for a certain `companies_id` .

Any suggestions how to speed up the above query?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please share the `EXPLAIN` for your query. Maybe there are indices missing?

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Always name the columns you actually want returned,

Comment: From your table definition I see that there is no PRIMARY KEY. What is the purpose of the column `id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using correlated subquery -

```
SELECT * FROM prices p
WHERE p.id = 
(
   SELECT MAX(pp.id) FROM prices pp where p.companies_id=pp.companies_id
) AND p.companies_id = 3431
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Or an uncorellated one...

(Actually, this answer looks a bit wrong, but without a data set and desired result, I'm not sure what needs fixing)

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , n.eed
  FROM prices p
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT companies_id
            , MAX(id) id
         FROM prices 
        GROUP 
           BY companies_id
     ) x
    ON x.companies_id = p.companies_id
   AND x.id = p.id
 WHERE p.companies_id = 3431
 ORDER 
    BY p.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described the indexes on your table, and you should definitely look to optimise those if not done already. You also stated you are looking for the latest price, but you are ordering by id rather than created_at - are there situations where a price record may have a created_at date that is out of sequence with it's ID? If so you might consider using the created_at column instead (and making sure it's appropriately indexed).

Regarding the SQL query, depending on the number of records for each company, how you expect that to change over time, and how you have indexed the table, you **may** actually find a simple limit yields a quicker result time than using a subquery. There are a lot of caveats to this approach though, the below article gives more information, make sure this suits your overall use case.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    prices p
WHERE
    p.companies_id = 3431
ORDER BY
    p.created_at
DESC
LIMIT 1
```

https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: I would also agree with @Strawberry's comment that you should really select specific columns if possible, rather than *.